# Helm-mini: Show .txt and .log buffers

Tags: helm

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Package helm

Here content of my Helm-mini:

[image: step1]

As you can see there are buffer with extensions `.log` and buffers with extenstions `.txt`
If I want to show only buffer with extensions `.txt`

I use pattern: `.txt`

Here result:
[image: step1]

Question:
Is it possible to show all buffers with extenstions `.log` and extensions `.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the mode line, you can type `C-h m` for help. It says you can use regular expression to match the buffer name, so this pattern might work for you:

```
^.*.txt\|.*.log
```

or more accurately

```
^.*\.\(txt\|log\)
```

Comment: It's very long expression. It's very difficult for me to remeber it. It's will be good if expression is more simple. Something like this:  .log|.txt

Comment: @Alex you can ask the maintainer of helm for help by filing an issue on github https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm